# Multiple Sub Domains - Same root dir

Tags: dns, plesk

I have a shared server I access via Plesk and manage for a client.

I needed to set up sub-domains but I was unable to use wild-card sub-domains so what I did was to create sub-domains as sub-folders. All sub-domains use the same app (with small changes per sub-domain, such as logo, title etc).

At the moment I have 42 sub-domains, which are all relatively low-traffic sites. Instead of creating a sub-folder (42 in this instance) for each I created one sub-folder and pointed all sub-domains to this folder, which has an index.php file in which is the entry point to the common application.

My question is is this a suitable solution? other than moving servers I cant see a more manageable solution? As I will have many more sub-domains in the near future. What do you think is the critical number of sub-domains? But I guess it depends on how much they are trafficed?

Just after any words of wisdom, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ServerAlias directive

Comment: Hi, are you saying I can use this via a httpd.ini? I am using ISAPI rewrite 2 so dont cannot use .htaccess. thanks, also could you provide a simple example? :)